# How to create a shopping cart calculator

Tags: python, calculator

I am writing a program which takes one input (a number of product) and gives one output (price of the product):

- Drink: $2.25
- 6-pack: $10
- 25% discount if more than $20

((Sorry if my code is really bad I'm a newbie))

```
print( "How many drinks do you want?" )

drinks = input( "Enter number: ")

total = int(drinks)

single = 2.25

six = 10

single * 6 = six

if total > 20:

    total * 0.75

print( "That will be a total of: ", total, "dollars")
```

I'm confused how to make it so that, after I have changed the input value to an int, how can I separate and calculate it based on my pricing criteria. Please help?

Comment: `six = 5` is an interesting choice for a variable name... you never use your `drinks` variable. `total * 0.75` does not change the value of `total`; `total *= 0.75` would.

Comment: For what reason are the variables `single` and `six`? In the end, you just print the value of `total` (== drinks)?

Comment: its so that every multiple of 6 from the input changes the pricing to a six pack e.g. if a person buys 4 drinks then 4*2.25=9 but if they buy 7 then 10+2.25=12.25 instead of 7*2.25, does that make sense?

Comment: I think I understood it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're looking for something like this. Hope it helps! I tried to keep your variable names the same so it would make some kind of sense to you. The line I commented out is an error.

```
drinks = input("How many drinks do you want?")
drinks = int(drinks)

total = 0

single = 2.25
six = 10

sixPacks = drinks // 6
singles = drinks % 6
# single * 6 = six

total += six * sixPacks
total += single * singles

if total > 20:
    total *= 0.75

print( "That will be a total of: {} dollars".format(round(total, 2)))
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `total = total * 0.75`?

Comment: Yes it should. Thanks.

Comment: i tried to use a similar method but when i put simply 2 drinks in the input it doesn't just double the single price i.e. instead of 2.25*2=4.50 it says 2 drinks=4.17?

Comment: and it says the price of one drink is now 3.08? im confused

Comment: I'm really not sure why your are getting lower values than the full price. It seems to be working for me (https://repl.it/repls/CruelRobustRotation).

Answer (score 1):

Okay so let's break it down logically.

You first take in the input number of drinks the person wants. You're assigning it to total right away, when you should actually assign it to a variable that holds the number of drinks.

You should then multiply the number of drinks by the cost per drink. You also need to check if the number of drinks are a multiple of 6 so that you can price them by the six pack.

Once you have calculated this check if the total < 20.

Since this is a homework problem. I will encourage you to try to solve it with this approach.

Comment: how would i 'check if the number of drinks are a multiple of 6 so that you can price them by the six pack'

Comment: Look up differences between division and modulu operations. That is where the trick lies. Hint- You will have to use both of them.

Some more hints. In python 7//6 will give you 1 and 13//6 will give you 2. Try to combine this with the rest of your code.

Comment: oh i see, interesting